# Angular <mat-list-option> custom height

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

In [this](https://material.angular.io/components/list/examples#list-single-selection) official example of `<mat-selection-list>` with `<mat-list-option>`. I want to give every item within the list a custom height.

I have tried:

```
.mat-list-option {
  height: 100px
}
```

And even tried to set the height to inside element using a selector. It won't work. Seems `mat-list-option` has a preconfigured height of `48px`.

Comment: Have you tried with mat-list-option{}

Comment: @Vega yes, I tried this as well. It doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, this looks a bit out of usual way of styling, but there is a hack.
And use mat-list-option and not the homonymous class:

css:

```
mat-list-option:nth-child(n){
  height: 100px;
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nukjrv?file=src/app/app.component.css)

Answer (score 1):

Should also include `.mat-list-item`.

```css
.mat-list-base .mat-list-item, .mat-list-base .mat-list-option {
  height: 100px;
}
```

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q3y6k8?file=src%2Fapp%2Flist-single-selection-example.css